# Installing DNF on RHEL8 minimal image fails due to libdw and other dependencies

Tags: rpm, rhel8, dnf

I am building an Ansible Execution Environment using this image as a base:

`registry.redhat.io/ansible-automation-platform-22/ee-minimal-rhel8:1.0.0-373`

It does not include either `yum` or `dnf` binaries from what I can see, since typically it would not be needed to just launch Ansible playbooks. However I need to be able to install additional software dependencies.

To resolve I have been trying to install `dnf` from RPM and resolving dependencies manually as I go. These are the last 4 dependencies I need to resolve:

```
libdw.so.1()(64bit) is needed by python3-rpm-4.14.3-26.el8.x86_64
libimaevm.so.2()(64bit) is needed by python3-rpm-4.14.3-26.el8.x86_64
librpmbuild.so.8()(64bit) is needed by python3-rpm-4.14.3-26.el8.x86_64
librpmsign.so.8()(64bit) is needed by python3-rpm-4.14.3-26.el8.x86_64
```

I found people suggesting to install `elfutils` but I installed several variants of that package and it doesn't resolve those deps, it just adds to the list.

Answer (score 1):

There is `microdnf` present in the base image. It has limited functionality but for basic installation it is good enough.

[How to build Ansible execution environment images for unconnected environments](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ansible-execution-environment-unconnected)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out using a different RHEL8 box and running the command `locate` against each missing binary and then running `rpm -qf` against the full binary path to see what package provides that binary.

After a bit of trial and error, here is the full list of RPMs I installed to get `dnf` working on this particular instance of RHEL8:

```
dnf-4.7.0-18.el8.noarch.rpm
dnf-data-4.7.0-18.el8.noarch.rpm
elfutils-default-yama-scope-0.189-2.el8.noarch.rpm
elfutils-libs-0.188-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
gdbm-1.18-2.el8.x86_64.rpm
ima-evm-utils-1.3.2-12.el8.x86_64.rpm
libcomps-0.1.18-4.0.1.el8ui.x86_64.rpm
libdwarf-20180129-4.el8.x86_64.rpm
libreport-filesystem-2.9.5-10.el8.x86_64.rpm
platform-python-3.6.8-51.el8_8.1.x86_64.rpm
platform-python-setuptools-39.2.0-7.el8.noarch.rpm
python3-dnf-4.7.0-18.el8.noarch.rpm
python3-gpg-1.13.1-11.el8.x86_64.rpm
python3-hawkey-0.63.0-14.el8_8.x86_64.rpm
python3-libcomps-0.1.18-4.0.1.el8ui.x86_64.rpm
python3-libdnf-0.63.0-14.el8_8.x86_64.rpm
python3-libs-3.6.8-51.el8_8.1.x86_64.rpm
python3-pip-wheel-9.0.3-22.el8.noarch.rpm
python3-rpm-4.14.3-26.el8.x86_64.rpm
python3-setuptools-wheel-39.2.0-7.el8.noarch.rpm
rpm-build-libs-4.14.3-26.el8.x86_64.rpm
tpm2-tss-2.3.2-4.el8.x86_64.rpm
```